# Sliding Window correlation vs cosine of relative phase

Tags: phase, cross-correlation, synchronization

I create two band limited signals having a specific time-varying covariance at each time point using cholesky decomposition. My aim for this experiment was to show a scenario where sliding window correlation performs well at estimating this time-varying connection between the two signals while phase synchrony fails. However upon performing this, the correlation between the phase synchrony and the actual time-varying connection is about 0.7, which is high. I am interested in knowing the relationship between phase synchrony and SWPC when using Cholesky decomposition.

Phase synchrony is computed by taking the cosine of the phase difference (estimated using Hilbert transform)